# printing a right triangle in python starting with input n with rows n

Tags: python, loops, printing

I am printing a right triangle in python of numbers that is supposed to look like this:

```
5
5 4
5 4 3
5 4 3 2 
5 4 3 2 1
```

I am able to print a right triangle using a nested loop but I cannot figure out how to print the numbers backwards I can only get it working from 0...n

Code:

```
for row in range(1, lastNumber):
    for column in range(1, row + 1):
        print(column, end=' ')
    print("")
```

Comment: Hint: Ranges are `range(start, stop, step)`; start can be higher than stop, and step can take a negative integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the python docs on `range`:

> ***class range(start, stop[, step])***
>
> If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If step is zero, ValueError is raised.
>
> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

In your case, you would want to say

```
for row in range(lastNumber, 1, -1):
```

---

You can see more about `range` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range.

Answer (score 0):

Check docs of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), there's `step` argument, which allow you to pass increment of each step. So, correct way to use it in your code will be:

```
for row in range(lastNumber):
    for column in range(lastNumber, lastNumber - row - 1, -1):
        print(column, end=" ")
    print("")
```

There's also a couple one-liners, which do same:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, range(5, 4 - n, -1))) for n in range(5)))
print(*(" ".join(map(str, range(5, 4 - n, -1))) for n in range(5)), sep="\n")
```